# camera2 api supporting no autofocus devices

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am using camera2 api for my camera development, I noticed that it supports the legacy version of camera. I am working on legacy one which above api 21 camera with no autofocus currently am using this one

```
 mState = STATE__WAIT_UNLOCK;
    mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
     CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
     mCameraCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewCaptureRequestBuilder.build(),
     mSessionCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
```

but facing an error which tells me

```
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
I/RequestQueue: Repeating capture request set.
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state CAPTURING
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JPG_20161119_023508_391909171.jpeg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.abukai.jpauya.camera, PID: 3302
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Bitmap.recycle()' on a null object reference
                      at com.abukai.jpauya.camera.CamaraIntentActivity.combineBitmapImage(CamaraIntentActivity.java:808)
                      at com.abukai.jpauya.camera.CamaraIntentActivity.CloseImageCapture(CamaraIntentActivity.java:760)
                      at com.abukai.jpauya.camera.CamaraIntentActivity.closeCaptureImage(CamaraIntentActivity.java:390)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Application terminated.
```

does anyone has an idea how to support those devices in camera2 api without autofocus?

Comment: The error is in `combineBitmapImage` with a null Bitmap. That doesn't seem to have anything to do with autofocus.

Comment: your right which is it happen most often because am using java to stitch/merge images after taking pictures and this error take place, I am still working on that one and not stable yet, but another concern is how to support those devices with no autofocus